# Any Java Code Coverage Tool for Solaris

Tags: java, code-coverage, solaris-10

I am not able to see the similar post so adding new.

Please suggest any free Java Code Coverage tool:

- Tool must be free/Open source.
- I want to run it in Solaris-10 server
- Code Coverage tool should not have any build/compile time dependency. I want to run this Code Coverage tool on the Solaris server where my Application has deployed.
- Tool should have capability to merge reports/snapshots.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [**Cobertura**](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)
- [**Emma**](http://emma.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Cobertura is really useful. HTML Reports are simple to read.

Answer (score 0):

[List](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage) of Code Coverage Tools for Java